# upload multiple Test cases at one time in ALM?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I'm trying to upload multiple Test cases at one go. How to upload multiple Test cases at one time in ALM ?

Answer (score 0):

- All flow files which you would upload should be updated with name attribute.
- Make sure the src folder has a properties file named as “multipleFlows.properties” or you would have to create it.
- Update the multipleFlows.properties file with all the flow ids and flow xml path that you would like to upload through ALMSync as mentioned below.

> ```
> Ex: multipleFlows.properties file should contain as below format
>
> flow1_id=flow1_xml_path
>
> flow2_id=flow2_xml_path
>
> flow3_id=flow3_xml_path
>
> flow4_id=flow4_xml_path
> ```

- Open the Run Configuration ALMSync >> Arguments tab and update the arguments as
  createTestCase flow_map multipleFlows